# How to view items on scroll view within the layout xml

Tags: java, android

I have made a scroll view but i am unable to see the whole layout i want to see the last button and the radio button on layout xml without running it on device/emulator is their a way to view all the items that are on the scroll view on the layout xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="button one" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:text="buttontwo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text two"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Buttonthree" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:text="textfour"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

The long answer is no, you cannot actually "scroll" in a scrollview in the xml preview screen in eclipse. The reason is, the code is not actually compiled and the preview screen is simply there to give you an idea.

If you really wanted to see the bottom stuff, just comment out or set visibility to gone for some of the items above it so that your items at the bottom appear.

Comment: but i have seen someone making the layout xml screen height like double to see all items on the single screen ...

Comment: you cannot change the screen height in the xml. You could potentially create a custom device configuration, but i don't see what the difference is between that and just hiding some of the items. Why you are not able to just test this thing on a device or simulator is also beyond understanding.